# Слово "присно"

Tags: лексика

Что означает слово "присно"? "Приснопамятный", "ныне и присно..." и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

ПРИСНО, нареч. (стар. высок., церк.). Всегда, во веки веков (во многих словарях разъяснение есть).

Answer (score 0):

присно — непрерывно, всегда, постоянно